Playwright: how to connect existing chromium browser in MacBook
test("Open chrome with existing session", async ({}) => {
  const userDataDir =
    "/Users/SinhAb/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/";
  const browserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir, {
    channel: "chrome",
  });
  let page = browserContext.pages().at(0);
  if (!page) page = await browserContext.newPage();
  await page.goto("amazon.co.uk/");
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
});

This is the code I have used, for this, new window in existing browser panel is getting opened but the URL is blank, it's showing "about:blank".

Now after those changes I made (at the staging ground) I will answer your question

Your code have couple of problems:
This code is launching Chrome with an existing profile, not connecting to an active Chrome session.
So if launching Chrome with an existing profile is what you wish for, here is the fixes:

The test name should be Open chrome with existing profile instead of Open chrome with existing session

The path of userDataDir is not the full and correct path, since it missing the drive name and the last directory which is User Data.
The correct path should look something like this:
C:/Users/SinhAb/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data

In order for this code to work properly, you need to close all Google Chrome sessions before execution.



The path is correct because OP mentioned to be on Mac. So windows paths won´t work.

I'm not that familiar with the differences though, but I'm pretty sure /User Data dir exists on both OS
